# How to Use Mongo Pojos in Bulk Upsert

Tags: spring, mongodb, spring-data

Hi i have a list of Mongo Pojo I want to use upsert .I don't know how to use My pojo's .

```
    @Test
  public void testAgentDataStorage() {
      AgentDataStorage a = new AgentDataStorage(124l);
      DBCollection collection = mongoTemplate.getDb().getCollection("agent_data_storage");
      BulkWriteOperation bulkWriteOperation = collection.initializeUnorderedBulkOperation();
          BulkWriteRequestBuilder bulkWriteRequestBuilder = bulkWriteOperation.find((DBObject) a);
          BulkUpdateRequestBuilder updateReq = bulkWriteRequestBuilder.upsert();
          a.getDataPoints().put("TOTAL_INCENTIVE_EARNINGS" , 13);
          updateReq.replaceOne((DBObject) a);
      BulkWriteResult result = bulkWriteOperation.execute();

  }
```

Here AgentDataStorage is my pojo and this code is giving error 
**AgentDataStorage cannot be cast to com.mongodb.DBObject** . 
Below is my AgentDataStorage

```
    @CompoundIndex(name = "account_date_idx", def = "{'account' : 1, 'date' : 1}", unique = true)
@Document(collection = "agent_data_storage")
public class AgentDataStorage extends MongoKeyedEntity<String> implements Serializable {

  public static final SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");
  @Field
  private Long account;

  @Field()
  private String date;

  @Field
  private Map<String, Integer> dataPoints = new HashMap<>();

  public AgentDataStorage(Long account) {
    this.account = account;
    this.date = dateFormat.format(new Date());
    for (AgentDataPoints dataPoint : EnumSet.allOf(AgentDataPoints.class)) {
      this.dataPoints.put(dataPoint.toString(), 0);
    }
  }

  public AgentDataStorage(String account) {
    this.account = Long.valueOf(account);
    for (AgentDataPoints dataPoint : EnumSet.allOf(AgentDataPoints.class)) {
      this.dataPoints.put(dataPoint.toString(), 0);
    }
  }

  public AgentDataStorage(Long account, Date date) {
    this.account = account;
    this.date = dateFormat.format(date);
    for (AgentDataPoints dataPoint : EnumSet.allOf(AgentDataPoints.class)) {
      this.dataPoints.put(dataPoint.toString(), 0);
    }
  }

  public AgentDataStorage(Long account, Date date, Map<String, Integer> dataPoints) {
    this.account = account;
    this.date = dateFormat.format(date);
    this.dataPoints = dataPoints;
  }

  public AgentDataStorage(String account, Date date) {
    this.account = Long.valueOf(account);
    this.date = dateFormat.format(date);
    for (AgentDataPoints dataPoint : EnumSet.allOf(AgentDataPoints.class)) {
      this.dataPoints.put(dataPoint.toString(), 0);
    }
  }

  public AgentDataStorage(String account, String date) {
    this.account = Long.valueOf(account);
    this.date = date;
    for (AgentDataPoints dataPoint : EnumSet.allOf(AgentDataPoints.class)) {
      this.dataPoints.put(dataPoint.toString(), 0);
    }
  }

  public Long getAccount() {
    return account;
  }

  public void setAccount(Long account) {
    this.account = account;
  }

  public Date getDate() throws ParseException {
    return dateFormat.parse(this.date);
  }

  public void setDate(Date date) {
    this.date = dateFormat.format(date);
  }

  public Map<String, Integer> getDataPoints() {
    return dataPoints;
  }

  public void setDataPoints(Map<String, Integer> dataPoints) {
    this.dataPoints = dataPoints;
  }

  public void updateDataPoint(AgentDataPoints agentDataPoints, Integer value) {
    this.dataPoints.put(String.valueOf(agentDataPoints), value);
  }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Mongo Java Driver doesn't have support for complex types and it looks like your pojos are annotated with spring mongo db annotation.

You've couple of options here `MongoTemplate` and `MongoRepository`.

MongoTemplate: http://docs.spring.io/spring-data/data-mongo/docs/1.10.0.M1/reference/html/#mongo-template

MongoRepository: http://docs.spring.io/spring-data/data-mongo/docs/1.10.0.M1/reference/html/#mongo.repositories